# Plotting a curve that is fed by a function

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt





mu_0 = 50
mu_1 = mu_0*1.1
#mu_2 = mu_0*1.5
n= 3
sigma=4.32/math.sqrt(n)

horizontal_values=np.linspace(55, 75, num=101)

def critical_value(mu_1,sigma, alpha=0.04):
    c=stats.norm.ppf(1-alpha,mu_0,sigma)
    return c




c= critical_value(mu_1,sigma)
power = stats.norm.sf(c,mu_1,sigma)

print (power)
print(c)
```

Hello,
I need to plot a graph from these data: so when you enter different mu_0 you get different powers
I need to enter every element in that array(horizontal values) to that function(the one that calculates the power so we can see the power in accordance to the speed)
And after that I want to draw a curve accordingly.

TLDR I want to change mu_0 between 55 and 75 and use the results to draw  a graph. However I dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
import math
import ipywidgets as widgets
from ipywidgets import interactive
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def critical_value(mu_1,sigma, alpha=0.04):
    c=stats.norm.ppf(1-alpha,mu_0,sigma)
    return c

def func(mu_0):       # function for calculating power
    mu_1 = mu_0*1.1
    #mu_2 = mu_0*1.5
    n = 3
    sigma=4.32/math.sqrt(n)
    c = critical_value(mu_1,sigma)
    power = stats.norm.sf(c,mu_1,sigma)
    return power

horizontal_values=np.linspace(55, 75, num=101)  
power = [func(mu) for mu in horizontal_values]  # calculates power for different mu_0

plt.plot(horizontal_values, power)    # plot 
plt.xlabel('mu')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But the power when mu0 55 is 6.75, here we have over 0.9?

Comment: Can you check the formulas, for eg. in `critical_value`  you paas `mu_1` but use `mu_0`. Please correct if any corrections are required, so I can check for mistakes